# Is redis's return value a copy or referance

Tags: redis, c#-3.0

I heard of redis, but is's too heavy for my project. I decide to write some object cache myself, as below:

```
private List<Specification> _lsSpecification...// the object need cache, I will use R/W lock to protect it
```

As the read times is much more than write, I don't want code try-catch-finally block everytime I need read the object, as below:

```
        try
        {
            RWLock.EnterReadLock();
            // do anything about _lsSpecification
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            RWLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
```

Exactly, what I want to get is a specified 'Specification' object or the whole list. So I code method as below:

```
    public Specifiction getSpecification(int id)
    {
        RWLock.EnterReadLock();
        Specification specification = _lsSpecification.Find(c => c.ID == id).Clone;// assume a clone method is exist
        RWLock.ExitReadLock();
        return specification;
    }

    public List<Specification> getSpecifications()
    {
        RWLock.EnterReadLock();
        List<Specification> lsAll = _lsSpecification.ToList();
        RWLock.ExitReadLock();
        return lsAll ;
    }
```

As above shows, I call these method to get the object, and then use its copy value, it must be safe. But I still feel it is a waste for copying. I wonder know that whether redis could return an object or list, if it could, the value is a copy or reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Redis isn't heavy at all. It is very simple to install and use. You'll get it up and running with virtually no effort. I strongly encourage you to try it out when you can. With [StackExchange.Redis](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/) you have a simple, well designed and widely used C#-library to access your Redis server.

Redis is a key-value store where the value can be one of five different datatypes. In your case you could store your serialized `Specifiction` as `String` with the id as key, e.g. `spec:1`.

You will have to deserialize your `Specification` after calling `GET`. This `Specification`-object will not have object references set to or from it so it is a copy.

In a `SET` you could store all the ids.
You could fetch the ids with `SMEMBERS` and retrieve all items via `MGET` and deserialize them, again to new objects.